# Escape parentheses in Formula inside a VF page

Tags: visualforce, formula

I am trying to use the following formula inside a VF page.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!RIGHT(currentCase.AssetId,LEN(currentCase.AssetId)-(FIND(')-', currentCase.AssetId )+1))}"/>
```

This returns an error :

Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

The reason for this error is that the compiler is not interpreting properly this ')-' and thinks I am closing parentheses when what I am doing is searching for those characters.

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<apex:outputField>` expects to be passed an sObject in the value paramerter. You should switch your code to use `<apex:outputText>`.

The missing ')' syntax error is actually misleading and not referring to the ')-' part.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!RIGHT(currentCase.AssetId,LEN(currentCase.AssetId)-(FIND(')-', currentCase.AssetId )+1))}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error but not my problem. If I use outputtext, I get the ID of the asset displayed in the page instead of the name. Any idea on how can I do some string manipulation using the name?

Comment: @PepeFloyd I'm afraid you will need to add some more information to the question as Im a little unsure what your trying to do. Best bet is to add some examples of what an Id is and what a name is and how their fields / objects are structured.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Basically, we have Assets related to cases (standard lookup), I have a table in the VF page that shows the list of Cases that a portal user has. One of the columns(fields) visible in this table is the asset name, the problem is that this asset contains extra information that we don;'t want to display, therefore, the need for this formula(embedded on the page), I could create a formula field in cases to achieve this but I want to avoid it as we already have too many fields.

Comment: So basically current case is a var assigned to a list that contains fields from cases, I cannot access a field that we have in Assets via(currentcase.asset.thefield)that has what the formula does because portal users cant access fields from the asset object.

Comment: Ahh, I was about to suggest you use `currentcase.AssetId__r.Name`.
I'm afraid Ive seen similar problems with portal users before and the easiest solution was to add a formula field to the Case object.

Comment: You should be able to create a formula field on Case that looks like `Asset.Name` or even `RIGHT(Asset.Name,LEN(Asset.Name)-(FIND(')-', Asset.Name )+1))`. Then refer to this formula field in your page: `value="{!currentCase.Formula_Field__c}"`